# Is there any problem in my TURN server config?

Tags: javascript, linux, webrtc, vps, turn

I'm trying to implement WebRTC on my webpage. I want to  use TURN Server for communication, to be sure that everything will work fine for everyone. My TURN server, was configured as below. In Javascript are given data to TURN/STUN server. My webpage isn't done yet, because, i stuck at some problem, and I don't know, how to connect some users between each other. I gather fact, STUN/TURN give to broadcaster UDP port for communiction,  which is given to receivers, But I think, the problem is in browser <-> turnserver connection, because there aren't any port or ip adress  in localDescription, and only localhost adress instead. My question is, where is the problem? In config, or code. Both attached below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



    <p>
        This example shows you the contents of the selected part of your display.
        Click the Start Capture button to begin.
    </p>

    <p><button id="start">Start Capture</button>&nbsp;<button id="stop">Stop Capture</button></p>

    <video style="width: 960px; height: 540px;" id="video" autoplay></video>
    <video style="width: 960px; height: 540px;" id="remote-video" autoplay></video>
    <br>

    <strong>Log:</strong>
    <br>
    <pre id="log"></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

```
const Sender = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [
                {
                    urls: "stun:<ip-address>:3478" 
                },

                {
                    urls: "turn:<ip-address>:3478",
                    username: "<user>",  
                    credential: "<pass>" 
                }
            ]
        });






        var displayMediaOptions = {
            audio: false,
            video: {
                cursor: "always"
            }
        };




             navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions)
            .then(stream => {
                document.getElementById("video").srcObject = stream;
                for (let track of stream.getTracks()) {
                    Sender.addTrack(track);
                }

                return Sender.createOffer();
            })
                 .then(offer => {
                     Sender.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
                     console.log(Sender.localDescription);
                 })
            //.then(() => Reciver.setRemoteDescription(Sender.localDescription))
            //.then(() => Reciver.createAnswer())
            //.then(answer => Reciver.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer)))
           // .then(() => Sender.setRemoteDescription(Reciver.localDescription));
```

```
#**VPS server config (/etc/turnserver.conf)**


cli-password=12345678
listening-port=3478
#tls-listening-port=443

listening-ip=<my-server-ip>

relay-ip=<my-server-ip>
external-ip=<my-server-ip>

realm=<my-server-address>
server-name=<my-server-address>

lt-cred-mech
#userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf
user=<user:pass>
# use real-valid certificate/privatekey files
#cert=/etc/ssl/certificate.pem
#pkey=/etc/ssl/private.key

no-stdout-log
```

```
sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 409204313020118480 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=-
↵t=0 0
↵a=group:BUNDLE 0
↵a=msid-semantic: WMS
↵m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114 115 116
↵c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=ice-ufrag:j2gk
↵a=ice-pwd:y+bSuFIV7IeKCoFDVbB4Lvw5
↵a=ice-options:trickle
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 
1E:44:A1:31:E5:80:B1:3C:14:56:EA:7A:5F:9C:5B:58:75:DA:3C:ED:D1:EB:77:DD:58:B8:C5:96:68:CC:AF:7E
↵a=setup:actpass
(...)
```

Comment: Hi 
Your question is a bit confusing. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: Thank you for response! Overall I want to config TURN server, that could work with RTCPeerConnection in browser. Could You send me link with example of use WebRTC and TURN server? (if you have sth like that of course).

Comment: are you using coturn as turn server?

Comment: Yup, I using coturn.